# Narrow-phase CCD in FEM topology query (finite element method)

Tags: physically-based, physics

I am implementing IPC from siggraph2020, and one of its step is about CCD line search, where CCD is applied each iteration in the descent method in a part of the algorithm.

I have implemented CCD functions for primitive pairs (triangle-point, edge-edge), which returns time of impact (TOI) given the original positions of primitives and their moving directions.

What i want is the minimum of TOIs from all primitive pairs.

Now I wonder how do i build the topology of the tetrahedron mesh to find the primitives pairs that could possibly collide, and how to loop through them?

More specifically,

- what the will the data structure of triangles(faces) and edges be like
- what will the loop be like?
- How to examine if a vertex is adjacent to an edge, or is it a part of a triangle? simply looping through the two(three) vertices to see if they are equal, or are there other elegant ways?

The data i hold in simulation is probably like `Vector3 vertex[]` where each represents the position of a vertex, `Vector3 vertexDelta[]` where each represents the position offset of a vertex(which i want to test if intersection happen when `vertex[i] := vertex[i] + t * vertexDelta[i]`), and `Vector4Int tetra[]` where each represents the **indices** of the 4 vertices in the tetrahedron.

Apologies for my poor english.